# How to use AWS Route53 Reusable-Delegation Set when my domain is registered with GoDaddy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

Listed Below is the Brief Overview of my problem -

1. I've created a route53 reusable delegation as - `aws route53
   create-reusable-delegation-set --caller-reference 1234 --profile
   test`
2. I received the list of Name Servers and delegation set id
3. I replaced my GoDaddy Name Servers with the list of aws name servers I received by creating a delegation set

Now, when I create a Hosted Zone in AWS, the Name Servers of my Route 53 Hosted Zone don't match with my Name Servers I just updated with my Domain Registrar. What did I do wrong ? or, what should I do next to resolve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as you had to use aws-cli to create the reusable delegation set, you also have to use aws-cli to create the hosted zone.  Reusable delegation sets are not a console feature, but you can still add resource records to the hosted zone using the console, even if it has a reusable delegation set.

> You create a reusable delegation set and associate it with a hosted zone programmatically; using the Route 53 console isn't supported.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/route-53-concepts.html#route-53-concepts-reusable-delegation-set

Note also immediately above, on the same page:

> You can't change the name servers that are associated with an existing hosted zone.

...so you will need to create a new zone.  Changing the `NS` records in an existing hosted zone *does not* change the associated name servers.

Consider carefully whether you really need a reusable delegation set at all.  Vanity name servers not, operationally, a good strategy, unless you need them to simplify migrations from legacy external DNS.